# I saw the yt-watchme code in github. when i build ndk it not done

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I saw the yt-watchme code in github. when i build ndk it not done.

c file:

[ffmpeg-jni.c](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/ffmpeg-jni.c)

jni folder

[image]

when I build ndk it comes like this

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

`jint` and `JNICALL` should be separated by a space.

The other error is because you are not passing a format string.
Change that line to

```
LOGI("%s", x);
```

And when you get it compiling, please submit a pull request for other people to use :)

Comment: How can I remove the warnings

Comment: Fix the code or add flags that disable warnings `-Wno-pointer-sign`

Comment: I added this flag -Wno-pointer-sign but the warning  occurs.